# integration between j2ee and ADFS

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, saml-2.0, adfs

A Customer of ours decided to apply Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS)
and we use J2EE Technology.

The question is: how could I Integrate between my jsp/servlet website and ADFS?
Is there any sample code to integrate?

Comment: Fixed some grammar and some formatting as well. For readability.

Comment: @Suhaib we have [CAS](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS/Home) integreated with AD, which in turn uses [Spring SAML](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/), you should start there

Comment: you mean there is no way to integrate directly between ADFS and jsp/servlet or JSF Framework

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used the PAC4J library to integrate our Java EE application with ADFS 2.0 (and also other SAML 2.0 IdP servers).

- Home page: http://www.pac4j.org/
- Source code: https://github.com/leleuj/pac4j

There is also a demo project which shows how to use PAC4J to integrate your code with various authentication server, including Shibboleth (a SAML IdP). It does not use ADFS but you can easily customize it.

Have a look at README-ADFS.txt located in the root directory of PAC4J source code.